# std::istreambuf_iterator "peek" with std::ifstream

Tags: c++, iterator, ifstream, streambuf

When dealing with streams of data, I prefer to write the code in terms of templates and iterators. Often I need to "peek" at the next character. In order to make the code be able to deal no-bidirectional iterators, I have a snippet which looks like this:

```
template <class I>
I next(I it) {
    return ++it;
}
```

Obviously, this makes a copy of the iterator, increments the copy and returns it. This tends to work very nicely... except when the `std::istreambuf_iterator` is operating on a `std::ifstream`. For example, given a file "`test.txt`" with the contents "`ABCD`", and the following code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

template <class I>
I next(I it) {
    return ++it;
}

int main() {
    std::ifstream file("test.txt", std::ios::binary);
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> it(file);
    std::cout << *next(it) << std::endl;
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```

The output is:

```
$ ./test 
B
B
```

Instead of what I hoped for:

```
$ ./test 
B
A
```

In other words, incrementing one copy of the iterator, has the net effect of incrementing **all** of them!

I realize that file stream iterators have limitations in that they can only operate on what is currently in the read buffer associated with the file. So there may not be a solution which matches exactly what I want. Is there a way to do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it actually doesn't increment all iterators but rather *consumes the stream*, which in the end has the same effect. If you want to peek ahead, you need to do so on the stream itself, AFAIK.

Comment: yea, I figured. That's why I said "net effect". I figured that the character is "consumed" by incrementing, I was just hoping that there is something clever to do what I want.

Comment: You need to `seek` it explicitly, iternator don't work that way.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned 'peek' in the title of your post. std::istream has a `peek()` method. *Use it.*

Comment: but I want to work with iterators, ideally the code will be able to work with pointers or a `std::istreambuf_iterator` or anything that works like an iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Stream buffer iterators are one-pass iterators. You cannot move backwards and it doesn't have bidirectional functionality like `vector::iterator` and `string::iterator` to name a few. There is no way to create an isolated copy of a stream iterator which operates on a file stream independent of any other iterator instances. It is impossible because stream iterators, whether copied or not, work on the *same* stream object all the time. Copying an iterator does not copy the file stream.